# Self-deletion abuse must (somehow) be punished/made visible

Tags: feature-request, questions, deleted-questions

Again, I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092743/prolog-unexpected-output/24092775#) which shortly thereafter was deleted. I recall only vaguely having seen the user before.

Suggestion: Show in the profile the number of self-deletions. In this manner I can at least consider whether or not I will answer such a question at all.

I never ever have experienced this self-deletion frenzy in the last years. There must be something else that changed recently. Well, maybe general awareness of SO in schools and interference with their plagiarism policy.

Comment: I thought a question could not be deleted if it had an answer?

Comment: @Plutonix, only if it's upvoted or there is more than one answer.

Comment: The easiest way i've found to avoid the problem is to quit answering homework questions.  :P  It's generally a thankless job anyway.

Comment: It is already punishable, at least for OPs with a questionable (question) reputation. They will get a warning when they delete a question, saying that they are running the risk of being blocked from further posting questions. Furthermore, I would agree with @cHao - why not just let obvious homework and other poor questions go unanswered?

Comment: @cHao: Please note that the tags I'm interested in (all around [tag:prolog]) have ~4500 questions. So there is some interest still in answering such question. For tags a 100 times bigger, things look different, indeed.